# Python: How to deal with config files of libs (dependencies)

Tags: python, environment-variables, setuptools

**Context:**

I'm currently developing a product that is composed of 3 different Python projects: `P1`, `D1`, `D2`.

`D1` and `D2` are independent libraries (also developed by me) that should be installed through `setuptools`. `P1` is the main project and it depends on `D1` and `D2`. The libraries `D1` and `D2` require configuration files in order to set some custom parameters - let's say `config_d1.json` and `config_d2.json`.

**Question:**

As `P1` needs to customize the configuration of `D1` and `D2`, I was wondering the best way to set the location of these files.

**Current solution:**

I was thinking about setting the location of configuration files by using environment variables as `D1_CONF_HOME` and `D2_CONF_HOME` and inside `D1` and `D2` doing something like

```
D1_CONF_HOME = os.getenv('D1_CONF_HOME', '')
SETTINGS_LOCATION = path.join(D1_CONF_HOME, 'config_d1.json')
```

but I would like to know if it's really the Pythonic way to go (I come from Java world and we usually do it like that).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Pythonian it is, but this is how I did it. In setup.py I have:

```
setup(name='pkg-name',
     ...
     packages=['pkg-name'],
     package_dir={'pkg-name':'pkg-dir'},
     package_data={'pkg-name':['config/cfg1.json', 'config/cfg1.json']},
     ...
```

Please notice that 'config' is a sub-folder of 'pkg-dir' in your project.

The last thing that you'll need to do is to write functions that will find a package and a config path. These function will work **only**  if you implement it in a library, not in your project P1. In my case, I've created a Helper module in my lib and put them to that module, so I could all them from my project P1 as Helper.get_config_dir().

```
def get_pkg_dir():
  f = __file__
  for _ in range(100)
    f = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(f))
    if re.search(r'pkg-name$', f) is not None:
      break;
  return f

def get_config_dir():
  return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(get_pkg_dir(), 'config')
```

I think this approach is better than taking care of env variables.

Comment: Interesting solution. Thank you for your input, @Oleg. I was wondering though how `P1` would make a new config file - like `cfg2.json` - visible to your library module.

Comment: When you have an access to your config directories @ runtime, you can create or modify configuration files on fly. Right?

Comment: Well, what I want to do is to have a default configuration file inside the library and be able to specify another one iff necessary. I wasn't expecting to make change to the default configuration file inside the library. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: That was exactly my goal as well - to have a default JSON config that I could create in my project and then install it with setuptools to a package directory during a normal setup process, so this part is addressed. If by "specifying" another one you mean creating it on fly, then you can do it as well by creating a new file in a lib's package directory from your P1 project.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's a fair approach. I just don't know if we should be adding files inside lib's folder. In my case for instance, `D1` and `D2` were installed in a place where ordinary users don't have write permissions.

Comment: You can add write permission to that file only. It's not different from your CONF_HOME approach. However, if your configuration is per user, you'll need to consider individual user's configs stored in individual user's folders.